# Visual C++ ODBC application cannot connect to MySQL database

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-c++, odbc

I'm writing my first database application following a sample program the teacher given, but neither the sample, nor my own program can't connect to the database. (The JDBC sample program can, so the server should be OK).

I have these vars in the class declaration:

```
SQLHENV env;
SQLHDBC dbc;
SQLHSTMT stmt;
SQLRETURN ret;
```

Here's the constructor of my database handler class, that's where the connection should be made:

```
DBModule::DBModule(string server, string database)
{
this->server = server; //"localhost" is loaded into it
this->database = database; //"test" is loaded into it, of course it exists on the server

SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &env);
SQLSetEnvAttr(env, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (void *) SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0);
SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, env, &dbc);

command = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};SERVER="+this->server+";DATABASE="+this->database+";";
//command looks like this now:
//"DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=test;"

ret = SQLDriverConnect(dbc, NULL, (SQLWCHAR *)command.c_str(), SQL_NTS, NULL, 0, NULL, SQL_DRIVER_COMPLETE);

if (!SQL_SUCCEEDED(ret)) {
    err += CONNECT_DATABASE*DATABASE_UNREACHABLE;
    good = false;
    return;
} else {
    good = true;
}

SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, dbc, &stmt);

command = sysToStd(DBINIT);

SQLPrepare(stmt, (SQLWCHAR *)command.c_str(), SQL_NTS);
ret = SQLExecute(stmt);
}
```

The ret at SQLDriverConnect gets a -1 value.

I'm using the latest XAMPP as server with all the default settings (so i'm "root" and there is no password). I've tried adding UID=root to the connection string, but it did the same.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The ODBC driver configuration stuff in the mySQL ODBC connector's user interface has a "test connection" button. Have you tried it?

Comment: I don't think I have that...
This means I should install something for this to work?
Sorry, I'm a real noob with this, all I know is written in the above code :P
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably do not have MySQL ODBC drivers installed. JDBC works because you need not "install" them: they are some .jar files that can come with Java application. If you will use ODBC then install MySQL ODBC drivers, configure connection in ODBC Manager as System DSN, then from ODBC manager check if it connects to database (most ODBC drivers I know have "test connection" button).

When such test shows you "connected" or similar, then you can test if your application connects. Your connect sting looks like:

```
  DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};SERVER=...;DATABASE....
```

so according to: http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql#p30 it looks you are trying to use MySQL Connector/ODBC 3.51

Maybe database is not listening on dafult port?

Comment: I've tried all these, but neither worked (I've also tried MySQL Connector C and C++, but they were the same), so I've made a primitive JDBC program that transfers queries to the server and it's response back to my C++ app. It's quite slow this way, but at least works.
But thanks for the advice anyway.

Comment: Have you checked in ODBC manager that MySQL driver is installed? Is it on drivers list?